# Creating a dynamic checkboxes against the list of items using mvvm light wpf?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have the following scenario:

I have one window say MainWindow where I am displaying the list of activities as per the specific user from the database. There is a one button present on the window. By clicking on that button a new window is getting opened having all the list of activities from the master table. Now I want add a chechbox on the second window against each item dynamically so that user can select/deselect the activities. Those selected/deselected values should save in the database and Parent/MainWindow should refreshed after clicking on the done button and changes should reflect in the MianWindow. But I am not getting how to dynamically creating the checkboxes against each list item and binding with the xaml and select/deselect the checkbox.

Kindly suggest with samples  or examples.

Thanks

Comment: Check my Updated Answer. You can edit your question rather than producing an answer which actually not is.

Answer (score 3):

You can customize your listviewitem using the ListView's [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemtemplate.aspx). Add a checkbox
and a textblock to a panel which would constitute your datatemplate.

**Update**

***The Model:***

```
public class Activity
{         
    public Activity(int id, string name) 
    { 
        ID = id;
        Name = name;        
    } 

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    

}
```

***The ViewModel for ListViewItem in Second Window:***

```
public class ActivityViewModel
{
    Activity _model;

    public ActivityViewModel(Activity model, bool isSelected) 
    { 
        _model = model;
        IsSelected = isSelected; 
    }        

    public string Name { get { return _model.Name; } }

    /* Since the view has a checkbox and it requires a bool value for binding
       we create this property */
    public Nullable<bool> IsSelected { get; set; }       
}
```

***The DataAccess***

```
public class DaoDailyActivities 
{ 
    string activityName = "";  
    bool IsSelected; 

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=172.16.32.68;database=ParentalHealth;uid=sa;pwd=Emids123"); 

    public IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivities() 
    {  
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_GetActivities", con); 
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open(); /* It is safe to open connections in a try block */

        SqlDataReader readerActivities = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (readerActivities.Read()) 
        {           
            yield new Activity(readerActivities["ActivityID"].ToString(), readerActivities["ActivityName"].ToString());            
        } 
    }         
}
```

***The ViewModel for SecondWindow:***

```
public class SecondWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    DaoDailyActivities _rep = new DaoDailyActivities();

    public ObservableCollection<ActivityViewModel> AllActivities { get; set; }

    public SecondWindowViewModel()
    {
        LoadAllActivities();
    } 

    LoadAllActivities()
    {
        foreach(Activity activity in _rep.GetActivities())
        {
            AllActivities.Add(new ActivityViewModel(activity, (activity.ID % 2 == 0)));
        }
    }
}
```

***The XAML:***

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllActivities}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
         <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done that. Values are coming alongwith the checkboxes. Values are coming from database and checkboxes are dynamically created. Now I want to preselect the checkboxes as per the table values. How to do that. I am returning the list.

Thanks

Comment: @Tarun: You can bind the values to the checkbox using a converter-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx. Send me a sample of List data.

Comment: Hi Veer,

I have one MainWindow, where am showing List of activities asp per the specific user. There is a button to add new activities in the existing list. By clicking Add NewActivities button a new window is getting opened with the whole list and with the specific user activities with preselect checkboxes. I want to preselect the values as per the database values. 
MainWindow:
Jogging
Running
Add new Activities window:
Jogging checkbox
Running checkbox
Napping

Kindly Suggest?

Comment: @Tarun: If Activity is a ViewModel and not a Model, then you can better add a property called isPresent. Else you should create a ViewModel that would act as a mirror for your model for other properties and also includes this extra property isPresent so that it could be bound to the checkboxes. Tell me if activity is a Model or a wrapper. In either case, show some code of your Activity class so that I would modify it and you may get the picture better. Also tell me more about the new Window. Does it have an OK/Cancel button to save changes? or data is saved on clicking the checkboxes at once?